# adding a column in mysql so that depending on which user logs in they go to a specific page

Tags: php, mysql

below is the authorisation script (from login). I want to send a user to a specific page depending on (new column called company to be added to database table) a user and their company.
Current script, even if someone can point me in the direction I would appreciate it:

```
<title>authorise</title>
<?php

session_start();



    $un = $_POST['username'];
    $pw = $_POST['password'];

    if ($pw != ''){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $un;

        echo "Incorrect username / password";
    }

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login_site","root","black$23");
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username)=:username";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':username',strtolower ($_POST['username']));
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
{

    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    require('blowfish.php');
    require('bcrypt.class.php');
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
    if($bcrypt->verify($_POST['password'],$row['password']))
    {

        echo"logged in!!";
        header("Location: hollyfort/123.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Though this doesn't answer your question, you really don't want to be using the root user to do this sort of thing. Create a user that has *only* the specific privileges needed to do the job.

Comment: This is just for testing on laptop

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a table with the userID and a page id (or perhaps w/ the companyID and a pageID), so you can determine the page to be returned by the user or company. Maybe you even want both tables, e.g. if you want all employees of a company to get a certain site, but the CEO should get to a special site where he can see all his employees' activities.

you then first check, if an entry for that user exists (if it does, you return the page). if not, check if an entry for the company exists. if you cannot find an entry, you probably want to return a default page

Comment: @dabollix Do you want to do this for one company or for many different companies?

Comment: 2 companies to start with

Answer (score 0):

all is ok - I setup company variables to check against the database column and it works :)